# how to set the buttons size inside a spinner in kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spinner, kivy

kindly need to know how to change or control the size of the special buttons inside a kivy spinner. note: my spinner is in the kv language and not in python and looks like this:

```
Spinner:
    id:some_id
    text:"some text"
    values:("1","2","3")
    size_hint:(None,None)
    size: root.width/4,root.height/12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons inside of `Spinner` are of type passed to `option_cls` property. The default one is `SpinnerOption` class, which is actually a subclass of `Button`. You can change class passed to this property (it must have `text` property and `on_release` event) or modify `SpinnerOption` class globally:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

Builder.load_string('''
<SpinnerOption>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 20, 20

<MyWidget>:
    Spinner:
        id:some_id
        text:"some text"
        values:("1","2","3")
        size_hint:(None,None)
        size: root.width/4,root.height/12
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):pass

runTouchApp(MyWidget())
```

Using custom buttons:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 20, 20

<MyWidget>:
    MySpinner:
        id:some_id
        text:"some text"
        values:("1","2","3")
        size_hint:(None,None)
        size: root.width/4,root.height/12
''')

class MyButton(Button):
    pass

class MySpinner(Spinner):
    option_cls = ObjectProperty(MyButton) # setting this property inside kv doesn't seem to work

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass    

runTouchApp(MyWidget())
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want @Nykakin but still one question though : how to set height and width in proportion to the root widget if i adopt the first solution (global overwriting of the class SpinnerOption?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know and after trying to code it I can say it's more complicated that I thought.

Comment: i just discovered that the spinner options are scrollable by default,and this might solve the problem. you see, i have built a payroll calculator application that i wish to run on every android device and my concern was the small displays because the spinners when opened won't fit to the small screens. it is really nice on Nexus 4 and amazing on Samsung s4 but for small devices with 240x320 display...

Comment: What about listing buttons in several columns instead of just one...? This allows you to save space too.

Comment: of course i did so but there are 3 spinners too, with which you can select combinations of family status , number of children... send me your gmail or your whatsapp number so that i can send you a pic